# Do not save indexed captured groups, just the named ones

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm doing a `preg_match` with named capturing groups. When I print out the the `$matches` it shows the named groups, but also the default indexed groups, like so:

```
Array
(
    [0] => placeholder/placeholder2
    [p1] => placeholder  <-- Named, good
    [1] => placeholder   <-- Indexed, don't want this
    [p2] => placeholder2 <-- Named, good
    [2] => placeholder2  <-- Indexed, don't want this
)
```

With this piece of code:

```
$str = 'placeholder/placeholder2';

preg_match('#(?P<p1>[[:alnum:]]+)/(?P<p2>[[:alnum:]]+)#', $str, $matches);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($matches);
echo '</pre>';
```

[Demo available here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/mTwN1F)

I only want to have the named groups in my `$matches` result. How can I avoid it to also save the matches as an indexed group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's impossible to to natively with [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)- because it implements PCRE and this can't be done by PCRE.

Most simplest way is just handle output array:

```
foreach($matches as $key=>$match)
{
   if(is_int($key))
   {
      unset($matches[$key]);
   }
}
```